# How to use for loop in vuejs methods?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

The function work till the first debugging point and then finishes, it does not execute or loop?
What Am I doing wrong here, any help is appreciated?

```
methods: {
    changeData(data) {
      this.data = data;
      this.data_to_show = this.data.data;
      this.source = this.data.source;
      this.database = this.data.database;
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      this.all_data = Object.values(this.data_to_show)[0];
      debugger;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.all_data.length; i += 1) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
          this.even_data_to_show.push({ i: this.all_data[i] });
        } else {
          this.odd_data_to_show.push({ i: this.all_data[i] });
        }
      }
      debugger;
    },
  },
```

Comment: Did you checked that `Object.values(this.data_to_show)[0]` returns an array?

Comment: yes it does, I use it for rendering.

Comment: When paused in the debugger try checking the value of `this.all_data.length`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For loop inside a method using Vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57891829/for-loop-inside-a-method-using-vuejs)

Answer (score 0):

i think `Object.values(this.data_to_show)[0]`,gives object. So, `this.all_data.length` will gives you `undefined` length. So, check once.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try by key in v-loops for Vuejs.

Basic example below:- so it would be v-for...but do not use V-if

v-for='product in products'>

Comment: this is the buisness changes, not a view/template change. So, use of v-for is not correct.